# How to display a date with a specific format AND Locale in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports, simpledateformat, date-formatting

Here is the extract of my jrxml:

```xml
<textField>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Exported on " + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z").format(new java.util.Date(), java.util.Locale.US)]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

And I obtain this error when compiling with Jaspersoft Studo 6.0.4.Final:

```
Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The method format(Date, StringBuffer, FieldPosition) in the type SimpleDateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (Date, Locale)
            value = "Exported on " + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z").format(new java.util.Date(), java.util.Locale.US); //$JR_EXPR_ID=28$
```

Which seems really strange because [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) do not have any `format(Date, StringBuffer, FieldPosition)` method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops actually I didn't put the `Locale` argument on the right method, here is the correct jrxml:

```xml
<textField>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Exported on " + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z", java.util.Locale.US).format(new java.util.Date())]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```